# How do I get to write a code with JS to repeat an input 50 times

Tags: arrays, function, loops

> One of your friends has been told to write her (or his) name 50 times by her teacher. As a JavaScript student, you have determined to help her.
> You decided to automate the name writing.
> This is because writing her name manually from 1 to 50 is tedious work. As result, you tasked yourself to write a program that will display your friend's name 50 times.

Comment: Please read  the [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) and  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). Just copy/pasting your assignments will not win you any friends.

Answer (score -1):

Either run a for loop , or you can use a string method called repeat.